# I can't run a program in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, command-line, chmod, makefile

I've got a problem with a program I downloaded last week from GitHub. I tried to `chmod` it (`a+x`), tick option to run it as a program, but it didn't help.

I don't get any notifications. It just does nothing. You can find this program [here](http://rfc2822.github.io/GfxTablet/#part-1-uinput-driver).

It's networktablet 64-bit, dynamically linked, tested with Fedora 18 and Ubuntu 12.10
([download link](https://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet/blob/binaries/networktablet-x86_64?raw=true)). The input driver must be installed on your PC. It creates a virtual "network tablet" on your PC that is controlled by your Android device.<sup>**1**</sup>

Do you have any solutions?

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>[GfxTablet](https://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet)</sub>

Comment: We need more information. What program did you try to install? Do you get any errors when trying to run it? How are you trying to run it?

Comment: I don't get any notifications. It just does nothing. You can find this progam [here](http://rfc2822.github.io/GfxTablet/#part-1-uinput-driver)

It's networktablet 64-bit, dynamically linked, tested with Fedora 18 and Ubuntu 12.10
([download link](https://github.com/rfc2822/GfxTablet/blob/binaries/networktablet-x86_64?raw=true))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tested on a different Ubuntu version, so may not work; why not try to download the source & compile that - several things may happen:

- It works, just like that!
- It gives a useful error report during compilation, pointing you to
  other things you need installed (probable)
- It causes further questions..

Also I note there's a possibility you may need to "Activate the module" for Xorg - did you follow that link & try it?

And finally, you did try running it sudo as it says?

Comment: I will try this, but I am new to Linux (Downloaded ubuntu just to try it) and it may be quite hard to me. But if anything goes wrong I'll post an update. Thanks.

And yes, I tried every command that I know...

Comment: [Here](http://s16.postimg.org/se4fuf2w4/Zrzut_ekranu_z_2015_03_17_12_47_02.jpg) is the screnshoot of permissions...